# Registro JSP en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Estoy intentando realizar un formulario mediante JSP e insertar los valores mediante MySQL. El problema que tengo es que si alguien se intenta registrar y el usuario existe me diga: "El usuario ya existe". No me funciona, no se, pero de alguna manera no me hace correctamente el while.
Aquí el código:

```
 // Variables de conexion
Connection con; 
Statement set; 
ResultSet rs; 

String sURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/loginjsp"; 
String userName = "root"; 
String password = "root"; 

//Parámetros index
String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
String repPass = request.getParameter("repPass");

//Si las variables existen
if(nombre != null && pass != null && repPass != null){
    //Si las contraseñas coinciden
    if(pass.equals(repPass)){
        try{ 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL, userName, password); 
            System.out.println("Se ha conectado"); 
            set = con.createStatement(); 
            rs = set.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios;"); 

            while(rs.next()){ 

                String nombreBD = rs.getString("nombre");
                String passBD = rs.getString("pass");
                out.println(nombreBD + "...." + nombre);

               //Si existe en la BD
                if( nombre.equals(nombreBD)){ 
                    out.println("<script>alert('Ya existe este usuario!')</script>");

                } else{
                    out.println("22222");
                    String consultaSQL = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, pass) values ('" + nombre + "','" + pass + "');";
                    int consulta = set.executeUpdate(consultaSQL);
                    out.println("<script>alert('Ya te has registrado!')</script>");
                }//end if
                out.print("1..");
            }//end while

            //Cerramos conexión
            rs.close(); 
            set.close(); 
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Error en acceso a BD"); 
        }//end try catch

    }else{
        out.println("<script>alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden!')</script>");
    }//end if

}//end if
```

Comment: ¿Este `out.println(nombreBD + "...." + nombre);` sí está imprimiendo los datos que hay y que son?

Comment: @Jonathanch Me imprime: Richard(Primera fila de la tabla)......Cristian(Nombre que he puesto de ejemplo en el input); osea que no me recorre todas las filas, que es lo que debería hacer.

Comment: ¿cuantos registros tiene la tabla?¿solo imprime una vez?
Tenga en cuenta que no está poniendo un `brake;` para que rompa el ciclo en caso de que encuentre ya registrado el usuario. También es importante que haga el `INSERT` fuera del bucle para que esté seguro de que ningún registro coincidió con el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta mal tu lógica.

Primero tu query debe ser así:

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM usuarios where nombre=?;
```

Y el parametro se lo pasas con un `pstmt.setString(1,nombre);` de este modo en el resulset recibes `total` y ya sabes cuantos hay, si es cero no existe y si es mayor a cero ya existe:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*) as total FROM usuarios where nombre=?;"); 
pstmt.setString(1,nombre);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
int total = rs.getInt("total");
```

De este modo ya no necesitas ese `while`.

Y por favor no uses Statement ya que es susceptible de ataques con injection SQL mejor usa [prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) y te evitas de problemas futuros.